# performance issue with ORDER BY clause with function call in select list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have issues in below query since below query uses a call to `PKG.GET_PHONE_NUMBER` in the selected list to get phone details and by using `ORDER BY` it takes close to 2 mins to complete for **16k rows**. without `ORDER BY` its quick.

Below `query` will get `PK key` column with description and to get phone details to call the function with below parameters to get primary, secondary and fax numbers.

```
    SELECT distinct PK_column , 
           description , 
           PKG.GET_PHONE_NUMBER (pk_column,'PRI') primary_phone_no ,
           PKG.GET_PHONE_NUMBER (pk_column,'SCD') sec_phone_no , 
           PKG.GET_PHONE_NUMBER (pk_column,'FAX') fax_phone_no
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY pk_column
```

Any help with tuning query is appreciated without any temp tables creations?

---

This function GET_PHONE_NUMBER below :

```
SELECT P.PHONE_AREA_CODE || P.PHONE_NUMBER INTO V_PHONE_NUMBER 
FROM PHONE P WHERE UPPER(P.PK_column) = UPPER(PK_column) 
 AND P.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE = IN_PHONE_NO_TYP;
```

Comment: Clauses like ORDER BY typically create more work for the database. For instance, if this table does not have any indexes that it can use to gather the results in order, the database will have to sort the results after gathering them, which will of course increase the time it takes to return the data set. 

Have you refreshed the table statistics? Have you compared the explain plans for the query with the ORDER BY clause and without? I would recommend taking those two steps (refresh table statistics, then compare explain plans) and seeing what you can glean from that info.

Comment: Do you really need `distinct PK_column`???  Surely a primary key column is unique, so why do you need the DISTINCT?

Comment: Please show in the question the definition of `PKG.GET_PHONE_NUMBER` function. The main source of problems is that the function is called 16k * 3 = 48k times in this query, causing 48k context switches from SQL to PL/SQL engine, back and forth, which always is slow.. My guess is that this function performs only a simple SELECT retrieving data from another table. You need to replace this function call with simple JOIN clause to the other table, for 16k records this will be super fast, even with the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @krokodilko / Matthew , This function GET_PHONE_NUMBER  below : SELECT P.PHONE_AREA_CODE || P.PHONE_NUMBER
      INTO V_PHONE_NUMBER
      FROM PHONE P
     WHERE UPPER(P.PK_column)  = UPPER(PK_column)                                       
       AND P.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE   = IN_PHONE_NO_TYP;

Comment: @krokodilko ...Thanks for all the input to make JOIN with function query ...it worked very well and its fast now

Comment: The `distinct` together with selecting the PK is completely useless

Comment: Are you sure? How long does it take to get entire results? Typically IDE's like TOAD limit the number of row output, i.e. Oracle does not fetch the entire result until you scroll down in the output grid. Sorting 16k rows should not be a big deal for an Oracle database.

Answer (score 2):

> > without ORDER BY its quick.

You mean, without the `ORDER BY`, you get results immediately.  But how long does it take to get *all* the results?  It's probably not quick.

Without an `ORDER BY`, Oracle can start giving you results immediately as it gets them.  But, with an `ORDER BY`, Oracle needs to get all the results internally so that it can sort them.  Only then can it start returning results.

This difference confuses many beginners into thinking one query is faster than another.  The query without the `ORDER BY` is only "faster" if you only really need the first few results.  If you need all the results, then they are probably about the same speed.

As far as tuning ideas, I cannot say much without seeing the logic inside `PKG.GET_PHONE_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

below is the final query which improves performance when that main query is joined with function query as krokodilko suggested :

```
SELECT   CC.pk_column   pk_column,
         CC.DESCRIPTION   DESCRIPTION,
         PRI.PHONE_AREA_CODE || PRI.PHONE_NUMBER  PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER,
         SCD.PHONE_AREA_CODE || SCD.PHONE_NUMBER  SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER,
         FAX.PHONE_AREA_CODE || FAX.PHONE_NUMBER  SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER
         FROM table_name CC
         LEFT JOIN PHONE PRI
       ON  UPPER(PRI.pk_column)  = UPPER(CC.pk_column)                                       
         AND PRI.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE   ='PRI'
           LEFT JOIN PHONE SCD
       ON  UPPER(SCD.pk_column)  = UPPER(CC.pk_column)                                       
         AND SCD.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE   ='SCD'
         LEFT JOIN PHONE FAX
       ON  UPPER(FAX.pk_column)  = UPPER(CC.pk_column)                                       
         AND FAX.PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE   ='FAX'
         ORDER BY pk_column
```

Comment: It would be even faster with functional indexes at `UPPER(pk_column)` on table  `table_name` and `PHONE`